# Information needed on scatter-gather list

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on developing a block driver in linux. The requirement is to allocate a huge chunk of memory(example more than 128KB, 2MB or 8MB or so...), divide the memory into small chunk and sent it through scatter-gather list. The scatter gather entries will be controlled by the user application.

I know there is a strict limitation of memory available in kernel. How can I achieve this at the kernel. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "chunk" not "junk", hahaha. Chunk means "piece", junk means "trash".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vmalloc` to allocate from virtual memory. This way, you can have all the memory you want (capped by the amount of memory there is).

From [`mm/vmalloc.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/vmalloc.c#L1710):

```
/**
* vmalloc - allocate virtually contiguous memory
* @size: allocation size
* Allocate enough pages to cover @size from the page level
* allocator and map them into contiguous kernel virtual space.
*
* For tight control over page level allocator and protection flags
* use __vmalloc() instead.
*/
```

`vmalloc`ed memory can be freed with, you guessed it, `vfree`.